# Optimize making a flat list from a list of strings each evaluable as a list

Tags: python, performance, optimization

For example, how would I optimally merge:

```
res_str = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
for example: ['[{'a': u'中国', 'b': u'美国', 'c': u'日本', 'd': u'德国', 'e': u'法国'},]','[{'a': u'中国', 'b': u'美国', 'c': u'日本', 'd': u'德国', 'e': u'法国'},]',]
```

into:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I used the following code, but is is not fast enough:

```
[x for j in res_str for x in eval(j)]  spend time 0.65s
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([eval(i) for i in res_str]))  spend time 0.57s
```

Is there a better way to write this?

apart from a generator

```
(x for j in res_str for x in eval(j))
```

other way

```
sum([eval(i) for i in res_str],[]) spend time 3.87s
```

this way:

```
import ast
import itertools
l = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
l = list(itertools.chain(*map(ast.literal_eval, l)))
spend time 0.95s
```

if use eval

```
list(itertools.chain(*map(eval, res_str)))
spend  time 0.58s
```

this way:

```
eval('+'.join('+'.join(arr)))  spend time 3.5s
```

this way:

```
import ast
import numpy as np
res_str = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
print(list(np.array([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in res_str]).flatten()))
spend time 1s
```

if use eval
    list(np.array([eval(i) for i in res_str]).flatten())
    spend time 0.58s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut That other question doesn't cover the key point here: how to deal most efficiently with conversion from string. So **it is not a duplicate**. The OP already shows a solution to that other question, that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @xin.chen You say your method isn't fast enough... and all the comments you've posted on answers given so far say that they're not fast enough either. What kind of performance improvement are you hoping for? Perhaps you could show us your time measurement of the various methods?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast` & `itertools`

**Ex:**

```
import ast
import itertools
l = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
l = list(itertools.chain(*map(ast.literal_eval, l)))
print( l )
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

- `ast.literal_eval` to convert string elements to list objects
- `itertools.chain` to flatten the list.

Comment: This method is not fast enough，my list length 22443, speed time 0.95s

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do it without eval / ast.literal_eval

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[map(int, w.strip('[]').split(',')) for w in l]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using List Comprehension**

```
import json
string_list = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
output_list = [y for x in string_list for y in json.loads(x)]
print output_list
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**Here the time taken is only to traverse the list and space complexity is the new list.**

```
import json
string_list = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
output_list = []
for str_list in string_list:
    output_list.extend(json.loads(str_list))
print output_list
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem a while ago. Here's how I did it

```
List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = []
for x in range(len(List)):
    for y in range(len(List[x])):
        result.append(List[x][y])

print(result)
```

Result prints [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

May not be as efficient as some other answers but it works and is more simple

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-line stylish solution without using `itertools` and easily readable:

```
import ast

myList= ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']

myNewList = [i for sublist in map(ast.literal_eval, myList) for i in sublist]

print(myNewList)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Here is also a second solution that may be faster:

```
import ast

myList = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']

myNewList = []

for sublist in myList:
    myNewList += ast.literal_eval(sublist)

print(myNewList)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below simple approach.

```
>>> arr
['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]', '[7,8,9]', '[10,11,12]']
>>>
>>> '+'.join(arr)
'[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]+[7,8,9]+[10,11,12]'
>>>
>>> eval('+'.join(arr))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>>
```

Another approach using **reduce()** and **lambda**.

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> arr = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
>>>
>>> arr2 = reduce(lambda list1, list2: list1 + '+' + list2, arr)
>>>
>>> arr2
'[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]+[7,8,9]+[10,11,12]'
>>>
>>> eval(arr2)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Okay, I've added another way.

Comment: same data ,Slower than the previous one

Comment: Okay, please tell me the execution time. I'll try to find a better way. Thanks.

Comment: my list length 22000,
['[{},{}]','[{},{},{}]']
the first way spend time:3.9s
the second way spend time:8.8s

Comment: And what is expected? So that I could try to do in that range.

Comment: for example:
['[{'a': u'中国', 'b': u'美国', 'c': u'日本', 'd': u'德国', 'e': u'法国'},]','[{'a': u'中国', 'b': u'美国', 'c': u'日本', 'd': u'德国', 'e': u'法国'},]',]

Comment: I am asking about time (minimum) that you expect.

Comment: if length 22000
i wangt spend 0.1s or less than 0.1s

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval`+`numpy.flatten`:

```
import ast
import numpy as np
res_str = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
print(list(np.array([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in res_str]).flatten()))
```

and:

```
import ast
l = []
res_str = ['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]','[7,8,9]','[10,11,12]']
for i in res_str:
   l.extend(ast.literal_eval(i))
print(l)
```